# iPhone: round double value

Tags: iphone

I have a few double values..35.44, 35.66 . I need to round them, and the result should be as NSNumber. The result should be 35.4 , 35.7. So how to do that ? Once again, the result should be as NSNumber, not NSString !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could print it to a string and use the format string to clip it to one decimal point.

```
NSString *stringRepresentation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", myDouble];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[stringRepresentation doubleValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 10, use a rounding function to strip the decimal, then divide by 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myDouble];
```

or

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)myDouble];
```

EDIT:
I misread the original question and thought you wanted to store a double as an integer value in an nsnumber.

So to answer the correct question, another option is an interim int:

```
double myDouble = 1.23;
int myInt = myDouble * 10;
myDouble = (double)myInt ;
myDouble /= 10; 
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble];
```

You might be better just storing the double in the NSNumber though and rounding it when you retrieve it later.

EDIT 2:

a more streamlined version would be:

```
double myDouble = 1.23;
myDouble = (int)(myDouble * 10);
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble/10];
```

it's probably better to not have to create an interim nsstring... imho

Comment: What happens if `(double)myInt` is larger than `MAXINT`?

Comment: somehow I think you know the answer to that ;) so good call. OP, make sure the int is less than maxint on the target device(s). However, the double values the OP gave are fine for this approach.